# How to disable pointers as template typenames

Tags: c++, class, templates

I would like to make it impossible to instantiate the following class when a pointer is used as the template typename:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass{
//...
T payload;
//...
};
```

So
`MyClass<int>` is fine but
`MyClass<int*>` is not.

It would be wonderful if I can prohibit the instantiation of the class with a `struct` that has a pointer in it.

Comment: You have [`std::is_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.  You can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to constrain the template to non-pointer types like

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer_v<T>, bool> = true>
class MyClass{
    //...
    T payload;
    //...
};
```

But this can give some pretty hard to understand compiler errors.  Using a [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) you can add your own custom error message like

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    //...
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer_v<T>, "MyClass<T> requires T to be a non pointer type");
    T payload;
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `static_assert` + `std::is_pointer_v`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer_v<T>);
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have C++11 to use [`std::is_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) and [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), you can define a specialization and leave it undefined:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {

};

template<class T>
class MyClass<T*>; // Requires non-pointer types

template<class T>
class MyClass<T* const>; // Requires non-pointer types

template<class T>
class MyClass<T* const volatile>; // Requires non-pointer types

template<class T>
class MyClass<T* volatile>; // Requires non-pointer types

int main() {
    MyClass<int> mc1;  // Works fine
    MyClass<int*> mc2; // Error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> It would be wonderful if I can prohibit the instantiation of the class with a struct that has a pointer in it.

This is not possible in C++.

Note that smart pointers *are* struct that have pointers in them; std::is_pointer does not recognise them so iif you want to prohibit them, you need to provide a separate meta-function (not very hard).